# jQuery .not() and .has() not working properly in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I want to append a div to the end of a certain `<li>` on a page.
I am not able to change the structure of the markup, so I have to drill in from the information I do have about it.
I start with `span.ruUploadSuccess` and find one that contains the text in my array `fileInfo[0]`.
I then go two parents up from that, and this is the `<li>` I need to append to.
I don't want to append this data if the div already exists though, so I check to see if that row already has this div (using `.has()`), and then filter those out from my results using `.not()`.

This works wonderfully in all browsers except IE7.  In IE7 it finds the proper row that I want to append to, but it's not filtering out those which already have this div.  This results in appending the same div twice (or more times).

Is there a simpler way to access this particular element?  Is there a reason why this would function differently in IE7?

My code for finding the `<li>` element to append to:

```
var row = $("span.ruUploadSuccess:contains('" + fileInfo[0] + "')").parent().parent();
$(row).not($(row).has("div.contactUsAttachmentFileSize")).append(label);
```

Here is some sample markup showing the structure I am trying to work through:

```
<ul id="content_0_leftcolumn_0_Attachments_RadAsyncUploadListContainer" class="ruInputs">
  <li>
    <span class="ruFileWrap ruStyled">
      <span class="ruUploadProgress ruUploadSuccess">test file (above 5mb).zip</span>
    </span>
    <input class="ruButton ruRemove" type="button" name="RowRemove" value="Remove" tabindex="-1">
    ===> DIV GOES HERE <===
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you might want to break up the `.not(.has())` line and check whether IE7 is choking on `.not()` or `.has()`, then do a workaround based on the results. Or consider dropping support for IE<8, and send Microsoft a bill for the time you spend writing hacks for their stupid browsers :)

Comment: @MrOBrian, I just did that now and it's the `.has()` that's failing to find any results.

Answer (score 0):

How about using filter().  It seems to work better than the not()/.has()

```
$(row).filter(function(){
    return !$(this).find('div.contactUsAttachmentFileSize').length;
}).append(label);
```

not,has fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/vxmGw/

filter() fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/B6v3A/

Comment: I get the same problem with this as I do with the previous answer.
`.find()` doesn't seem to be picking up the div in IE7.

Comment: I'm not sure then.. I don't have IE7 to test.  I did try it in in BrowserStack.com and it worked fine in that IE7

Answer (score 0):

I'd just recode it in a way that is more expressive of what you're actually trying to do. While what you have *should* work - it's hard to understand, and a more deliberate approach avoids the nuanced jquery stuff that's probably causing trouble in old IE. It's also much more clear what your intent is.

You really just want to test if the div exists already, and add it if not. So write it as a conditional.

http://jsfiddle.net/jamietre/ECVny/

```
var row = $("span.ruUploadSuccess:contains('test file')").parent().parent();

if (!row.find("div.contactUsAttachmentFileSize").length) {
    row.append(label);
}
```

Comment: That is definitely a cleaner approach, so I'll use that.
Unfortunately, it still doesn't find the div if it already exists.  In IE7 only again.